# I have two strings in my SQL Server database and I want to get specific values from them in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The first string is

```
www.abc.c/item/itemscode/012345678974-Thisisname
```

I want to get the only portion that is between `/` and `_` i.e only 012345678974

The second is

```
abc.org.c/items/item_database/number_3_of_10-klsnfdsfjsd.txt
```

From this string I want to get only 3 from "number_3_of...."

How can I do it. I tried many solution but i could not do it in past more than 48 hours

Comment: do you always have exactly 3 slashes before product?

Comment: To get the best answer to this type of question, you should include which parts of the string are "reliable" and will always be there.  For instance: Are there always the same number of slashes?  Is it always "itemscode/"?  Is it always "number_"?  Could there be other `-` in the first string?  Will the strings you're looking for always exist?  Will the strings you're looking for always be a certain length?

Comment: salmsn A and aaron Dietz thanks yo both of you guys for replying  the solution sugested by kashif Qureshi below works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve this. One way to achieve this is by using `Left()`, `Reverse()` and `Charindex()` function. You need to search for the pattern in your string and base your solution depending on that. Try this:

```
--First string     
    DECLARE @string VARCHAR(255)= 'www.abc.c/item/itemscode/012345678974-Thisisname';
    SELECT LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string))-1)), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string))-1)))-1);

--Second String     
    DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(255)= 'abc.org.c/items/item_database/number_3_of_10-klsnfdsfjsd.txt';
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2))-1)), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2))-1)))-1), 'NUMBER_', ''), '_OF_10', '');
```

Comment: Thanks JA, it works can you please help me to improve my reputation?

Comment: Can you please make the above answer as function I want to pass string in that function and get result. I am tried but failed...